# Query and manage many to many relation in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have the following simple groups with users structure in my app:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_membership
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_membership
end

class AccountMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    belongs_to :group
end
```

I now got a list of accounts, and wanna get the group that contains all those accounts (and only those).

Is there any way I can do it with `ActiveRecord` query or I have to do it SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@accounts_list = Account.all # for example
Group.joins(:account_membership).where(account_membership: {account_id: @accounts_list.pluck(:id)})
```

Comment: It should be `account_memberships` in the where clause. thanks! work really great.